# JavaScript works in debug mode but not working normal mode

Tags: javascript, debugging

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    urlHolder.checkUser = '${checkUser}';
    $('#checkUserForm').submit(function() {
        checkUser();
    });
});

var urlHolder = new Object();
function checkUser() {
        $.post(urlHolder.checkUser, {
            email : $('#email').val(),
            password : $('#password').val(),
        }, function(response) {
            if (response != null) {
                alert('Success! User has been added.');
            } else {
                alert('Failure! An error has occurred!');
            }
        });
    };
```

I'm using this code for checking user exist or not. When I used firefox debugger (breakpoint on alert() line ), it worked and server came back a response, but if I didn't put any breakpoint, alert doesn't work, but server came back a response. Note: not only alert() but also window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com"; didn't work.

Comment: I am seeing third question within 10 min that is containing incorrect `java` tag in it.

Comment: @afzalex Yea, seriously, people need to start tagging better

Comment: [Java is to Javascript, as Ham is to Hamster](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/images/xhtml2-html5/comic-960px.jpg). Let's see the markup for `checkUserForm`. I'll bet it has an `action` attribute that is submitting the form as you aren't calling `preventDefault` anywhere.

Comment: Actually, my application works on Java so I added java tag, I want to indicate, it's java on back-end but you are right, it is meaningless so I erased tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the following lines to prevent the form from being submitted:

```
$('#checkUserForm').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  checkUser();
});
```